# Too many equations for discrete state machine variables in when statements in Modelica

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

I have a contrived Modelica model in which a have a state machine variable manipulated by multiple `when` statements:

```
model WhenExample
  type State = enumeration(first, second, third);

  State   state;
initial equation
  state = State.first;

equation
  when sample(0, 1) then
    state = State.second;
  end when;

  when sample(0, 3) then
    state = State.third;
  end when;
end WhenExample;
```

When compiling under OpenModelica OMC, I get the following error:

```
[1] 16:46:39 Symbolic Error
Too many equations, over-determined system. The model has 2 equation(s) and 1 variable(s).
```

This kinda makes sense as I *do* have two equations for my single `state` variable. However, those equations only apply at discrete points in time, right?

Do I need to make sure all "manipulations" of a particular variable happen only in a single `when` statement?

Comment: Yes; adding two when equations makes the state have two equations and it is not possible for a Modelica to create a priority between the events, so `elsewhen` has to be used (or an algorithm section as shown below).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See Modelica Spec, section 8.5 Events and Synchronization:
https://www.modelica.org/documents/ModelicaSpec33Revision1.pdf

Just before section 8.6 there is an example that should help you.
Some code based on that is given below:

```
model WhenExample
  parameter Integer multiplySample = 3;
  Boolean fastSample, slowSample;
  Integer ticks(start=0);
  type State = enumeration(first, second, third);
  State state(start = State.first);
equation
  fastSample = sample(0,1);
algorithm
  when fastSample then
    ticks := if pre(ticks) < multiplySample then pre(ticks)+1 else 0;
    slowSample := pre(ticks) == 0;
    state := State.second;
  end when;
  when slowSample then
    state := State.third;
  end when;
end WhenExample;
```

Comment: Thanks. Putting my `when` statements in an `algorithm` section worked--and actually makes more sense.